# Subject-Tracking only available in LiveView

Tags: nikon, autofocus, viewfinder, live-view, nikon-d5600

I found this after three years of purchasing this camera (Nikon D5600) that it does have subject-tracking capabilities like other higher-end cameras. I always used eye-piece to take photos from ViewFinder (what Nikon says). Never used LiveView as I don't feel comfortable.

First of all, Nikon's ViewFinder and LiveView terms are very confusing. ViewFinder also is a LiveView. They should have rather used EyePiece and Screen instead.

Anyways, the subject-tracking option is only available in the LiveView. Is there an option that I get this option in the ViewFinder as well ?

[image]

Comment: See https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13880/what-are-the-technical-differences-between-using-a-dslr-viewfinder-and-live-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LiveView mode you have entire sensor involved. So you (camera processor) have the image to work on and to search for eye, face, etc.

With ViewFinder you do not have such information from the sensor, you have only focus and metering sensors involved. The rest are mirrors, reflective surfaces of prisms (in pro grade cameras) and you view the image directly. As mentioned in comment you can have subject tracking, but based on the AF points (called 3D).

Above is true for (probably) all nonmirrorless cameras.

Comment: Subject tracking is still available in viewfinder mode, but they don't call it that they call it 3D (I have no clue why.) - and, as you say, can't use the entire sensor, only the AF points.

Comment: @Tetsujin, thank you for clarification, will add it in to my answer :)

Comment: @Tetsujin, the DSLR has viewfinder focus tracking, but not subject tracking. 3D includes distance (the third direction), requires a D lens (distance reporting), and also incorporates color recognition from the matrix color meter. But it doesn't have subject/face/eye recognition...

Comment: When is it recommended to use LiveView ? I think it is suitable only when you are using Tripod and creating a video. Holding camera on hands and using LiveView is not easy.

Comment: @RKh, you can use it any time. But it is helpful when you have your camera over the head, on very low position, when try to monitor the surrounding, etc. And it is not required to have tripod to use it.

Comment: @StevenKersting - tbh, there is so little information even in the full reference manual, that it's hard to differentiate. I almost never use live view, so it's not really something I'm familiar with.