# Is something wrong with my camera display?

Tags: canon-600d, live-view, display

I have a question about my Canon 600d camera display. I got the camera two weeks ago and everything was working perfectly. I was taking photos through display and there was no problem. But today, when I tried to take photo through the display (I am mostly using manual mode), the display stayed black all time. The display is working normaly with all icons and in video-taking mode, but when I try to take a photo using display it is not working.I tried to delete the settings, turn it on and off...but I am desperate right now. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Thank you a lot (now I feel stupid as hell). I am really sorry to spam it here with such a silly question. It is my first camera and I am so scared that something is wrong all the time. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: No such thing as a silly question! If Philip's answer is helpful, please remember to mark it with the 'tick'/'check' to indicate that it helped.

Comment: @NickM: Nonsense.  Of course there are stupid and silly questions.  However, I don't see this as one of them.

Answer (score 8):

In order to use the rear LCD to compose pictures (as opposed to using the optical viewfinder), you must put your camera into "Live View" mode. On the 600D (and all other recent Canon SLRs), this is done by pressing the button marked with a camera icon and a red dot which is just to the right of the viewfinder:

[image]

It is worth noting that using the rear LCD rather than the optical viewfinder to compose pictures can remove some of the advantages of using an SLR - [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11531/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-the-optical-viewfinder-over-live-preview-to-take) gives a good overview of the differences.